# how to fix Hidapi did not initialise : Native library (com/sun/jna/android-arm/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)

Tags: android

I build an android application to communicate with a HID Usb device Freestyle Libre

for Linux, mac i used this library [Hid4Java](https://github.com/gary-rowe/hid4java) and it's seems well to works

now i wanna to do the same thing in Android OS

```
    HidServicesSpecification hidServicesSpecification = new HidServicesSpecification();
    hidServicesSpecification.setAutoShutdown(true);
    hidServicesSpecification.setScanInterval(500);
    hidServicesSpecification.setPauseInterval(5000);
    hidServicesSpecification.setScanMode(ScanMode.SCAN_AT_FIXED_INTERVAL_WITH_PAUSE_AFTER_WRITE);

    HidServices hidServices = HidManager.getHidServices(hidServicesSpecification);
```

the exception is caused by the last line of code

```
Caused by: org.hid4java.HidException: Hidapi did not initialise: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-arm/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)
```

the libary is a native C libary 
i searched already in multiples foums but still have the same problem

Any idea ? Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come back with my own answer, hoping that will help

after doing some research, you don't need to develop anything on android os,
use simply the native library of Android, here is a simple solution :
[AndroidHidJava](https://github.com/gary-rowe/hid4java/issues/83#issuecomment-653036701)